# How can I create a sqlite database file to be returned by a webservice

Tags: android, json, database, web-services, sqlite

I want to create a sqlite database file in a web service, so I dont have to read a json in the android device and wait for it to read the json, convert it to an object and then insert it to the database.

When the json is huge, with a lot of data, that process its to long for be waiting in an android device.

I would like to generate the database file of sqlite in the webservice, so that, instead of returning the json, it returns the sqlite database, and in android, I just need to save the database, so that, it is ready to use.

That would save a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

SQLite have libraries for almost any kind of server side language.
SQLite db is just a file so after is created you shall compress is in a zip and use volley library to dl the file over http.
Decompress the zip and connect to it.
I have no idea about which kind of data and which amount you need to transfer but if the data is organised properly the processing should be so long. Also you have to take in consideration that using JSON you can "ask" to receive only updates (delta) and this is something that is not possible if you download all the db each time.

**Update**: for this kind a data I would go to a different approach. Use [docs](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/#publishing) from google publishing api to upload every specific period of time the db in an extension pack for your app. so most of the dl'ing process is even before the "install" on the device itself. When the app is first running will contact your server and get the latest updates since the db was created (I suppose that even that is a week you are talking about less than a hundred rows)...

Comment: I just want to download this db one time. And then, insert and update.

Comment: what is the size of the data ? it's always something new ? it's different for each customer ?

Comment: It's a table of customers. It doesn't vary too much, but it's big. Like 35,000 rows.